# Creating a Custom Predicate using a String Value for the Numeric Operand

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

I am trying to pass in a string value ("GreaterThan", "Equals", etc.) for a numeric operand expression to a parameter.  I have created the code below which works, but it's "clunky".  I don't like the `if` blocks and I think there's a way to do this with a custom LINQ comparison predicate.  I tried to follow the reply posted in **[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19789386/how-do-i-create-a-generic-expression-that-has-an-expression-as-a-parameter)**, but I can't seem to follow it.  Any ideas on how to clean up my method?

Here's code showing how I want to pass a string value of "GreaterThan" to a function

```
    var myValues = new Dictionary<string, int> {{"Foo", 1}, {"Bar", 6}};
    var failed = DoAnyValuesFail(myValues, "GreaterThan", 4);
```

Here's the sample method that I wrote that's "clunky":

```
    public bool DoAnyValuesFail(Dictionary<string, int> dictionary, string expression, int failureValue)
    {
        var failureValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();
        if (expression == "GreaterThan")
            failureValues = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value > failureValue).ToList();
        if (expression == "LessThan")
            failureValues = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value < failureValue).ToList();
        if (expression == "Equals")
            failureValues = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value == failureValue).ToList();
        return failureValues.Any();
    }
```

**--- UPDATE - Final Version ---**

I think part of the confusion in the responses below is that I'm not that up to speed on my terminology of fuctions, predicates and delegates.  Sorry about that.  Regardless, I did want to clarify one thing and that is that the values of "GreaterThan", "LessThan" and "Equals" come from a configuration file, so they need to be "Magic Strings" that adjust at run time.

Therefore, based on the feedback from Matthew Haugen and Enigmativity, I have come up with the following code that I think works best for my needs.  I'm open to any suggestions if you think it's wrong or needs adjusted.

```
// These values actually come from a configuration file... shown here as hard coded just for illustration purposes
var failureValue = 2;
var numericQualifier = "<";

// This comes from my external data source
var myValues = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "Foo", 1 }, { "Bar", 6 } };

// This is the delegate (am I using that term correctly?) called Compare which is setup as an extension method
var failureValues = myValues.Where(x => numericQualifier.Compare()(x.Value, failureValue)).ToList();
if (failureValues.Any())
    Console.WriteLine("The following values failed: {0}", string.Join(", ", failureValues));
```

This then is my `Compare` extension method:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Func<int, int, bool> Compare(this string expression)
    {
        switch (expression)
        {
            case "GreaterThan":
            case ">":
                return (v, f) => v > f;
            case "LessThan":
            case "<":
                return (v, f) => v < f;
            case "Equals":
            case "=":
                return (v, f) => v == f;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("The expression of '{0}' is invalid.  Valid values are 'GreaterThan', 'LessThan' or 'Equals' or their respective symbols (>,<,=)", expression));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you want to do this. Seems to me that instead of creating and calling the method named "DoAnyValuesFail", it is actually more readable to code it as e.g. "var failed = myValues.Values.Any(v => v > 4);"

Comment: I also see that you've coded the method using the "create a superfluous object" anti-pattern. I.e. "var failureValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();" where you're just going to assign some different value to the variable later. Don't do that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Your last comment is generally a good point, but I suspect in this case the OP is trying to catch the case where `expression` isn't one of the three choices. Without the initial declaration this code wouldn't work.

Comment: @Enigmativity: ah, yes. You're right, in this particular case he needs the default instance due to the way the code is written. That said, I would argue it's better to initialize to null and return false at the end if "failureValues" is still null at that point. On the other hand, it's a short-lived empty List<T>, so maybe the superfluous object is doing no harm here. On the third hand, I still think it's an anti-pattern. :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho - Yes, I agree - it's an anti-pattern. Lead to failure it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your requirement to match the expression against a string I would be inclined to do this:

```
private Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>> _predicates =
    new Dictionary<string, Func<int, int, bool>>
    {
        { "GreaterThan", (v, f) => v > f },
        { "LessThan", (v, f) => v < f },
        { "Equals", (v, f) => v == f },
    };

public bool DoAnyValuesFail(
    Dictionary<string, int> dictionary,
    string expression,
    int failureValue)
{
    return _predicates.ContainsKey(expression)
        ? dictionary.Any(kvp => _predicates[expression](kvp.Value, failureValue))
        : false;
}
```

However, as others have said I think this is a better option:

```
public bool DoAnyValuesFail(
    Dictionary<string, int> dictionary,
    Func<int, bool> predicate)
{
    return dictionary.Any(kvp => predicate(kvp.Value));
}
```

And then simply call it like so:

```
var failed = DoAnyValuesFail(myValues, x => x > 4);
```

But then you are only one step away from making it even simpler:

```
var failed = myValues.Any(x => x.Value > 4);
```

No `DoAnyValuesFail` method required - meaning simpler code, less potential bugs, and no "magic" strings.

This code is much clearer and actually more terse than your original line.

Comment: thank you very much for this information.  As I put in the update to my post above, the "magic strings" come from a config file and so your use of returning a `Func` is what I was looking for, so you are getting the accepted answer.  Thanks for deciphering what I was looking for.  Let me know your thoughts on my updated code.

Comment: @bigmac - No trouble. My comment with you code would be that you should refactor your `Compare` function signature from `Func<int, int, bool> Compare(this string expression)` to `bool Compare(this string expression, int x, int failureValue)` - otherwise the code gets a bit funky when you return a delegate that you immediately call. The other option is to take a local copy of the result of `Compare()` and then call that in the `.Where`. Either one of those two to avoid the `Compare()(...)` double call.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by making it an `enum` rather than a `string.

```
public enum ComparisonType
{
    GreaterThan,
    LessThan,
    Equal,
}
```

Then, I'd change it to something like this. This will also improve performance, since only one matching value is required to return.

```
public bool DoAnyValuesFail(Dictionary<string, int> dictionary, ComparisonType expression, int failureValue)
{
    switch (expression)
    {
        case ComparisonType.Equals:
            return dictionary.Any(x => x.Value == failureValue);
        case ComparisonType.GreaterThan:
            return dictionary.Any(x => x.Value > failureValue);
        case ComparisonType.LessThan:
            return dictionary.Any(x => x.Value < failureValue);
        default:
            throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Of course, it's not *all* that much cleaner than what you've got. It's probably more reliable than depending on those `string` inputs, and that makes it a bit more readable. And not going via the `List<>` helps in my opinion. But I don't think there's much you can do beyond that. I mean, you *could* store the `Func<T, bool>` in a value that gets assigned to in the `switch` then use it afterward, which would normalize `return dictionary.Any(...)`, but I feel like that would make it less readable.

Ultimately I think it's fine as it is. Anything you do with an `Expression` will just take away from readability with functionality this simple.

Comment: Matthew, thank you as well for your information.  As I stated in my post, I am using a hybrid of your response and Enigmativity.  As I can only accept one answer, I accepting his as he helped point me to using a `Func` (something I didn't know I could do).  Regardless, I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You could Rewrite your method signature to use a Delegate like this:

```
public bool DoAnyValuesFail(Dictionary<string, int> dictionary,Func<int,bool> predicate)
{
     var failureValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();   
     failureValues = dictionary.Where(x => predicate(x.Value)).ToList();
     return failureValues.Any();
     //instead of the code above you could simply do
     //return dictionary.Any(x => predicate(x.Value));
}
```

Then when you call it you supply the desired expression like this:

```
var myValues = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "Foo", 1 }, { "Bar", 6 } };
var failed = DoAnyValuesFail(myValues, x => x < 4); //4 is what you had as the failureValue
```

Comment: Terry, thanks for the input, but your code doesn't really seem to help me as you have the `x => x < 4` hard coded into the parameter, where I really need to have the `<` value parsed from a configuration string.  Let me know if I am somehow missing something in your code.

Comment: the parameter of type func<int,bool> you pass into the method is the equivalent of (meaning does the job of)what you had by passing a string and a failurevalue.for example in your code you call doAnyValuesFail like this:'DoAnyValuesFail(myValues, "GreaterThan", 4);',its equivalent in my example by passing a delegate into the method and without needing the testing of the string or the aditional value of failure value like this:'DoAnyValuesFail(myValues, x => x > 4);'