# Custom rule pattern implementation

Tags: c#, linq, pattern-matching, predicate, rules

I have a list of business rules I need to apply to json data then output it back via an http post.

The rules dictate how to format strings based on their type and value.
ex:

- *first name, Capitalize the first letter.*
- *middle name: if one letter, append '.' at the end*

The challenging part is I want to be able to add/remove business rules without changing the code. So I thought about storing the rules and their definition in a sql table.

The table looks like this:

`|      RuleName       |     Action               |
|---------------------|------------------        |
|          padLeft    |         PadLeft<x>       |
|---------------------|------------------        |`

I don't know how to translate the rules to the action they are supposed to take. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26394130/creating-a-custom-predicate-using-a-string-value-for-the-numeric-operand) which is very close to what I'm looking for. Maybe I am over complicating this so I'm open to different suggestions

Comment: Those rules you describe require a full programming language, or something very close to it. You could search for .NET expression evaluator libraries (FLEE, NCalc, etc.) and if there's one that'll do all you need, store the expressions in the DB as strings. I would not recommend setting out to write your own for this project (as a project unto itself, I can't recommend anything more, at least as far as programming is concerned).

Comment: When you say, "without changing the code" - do you mean without changing *any* code or do you mean without changing other parts of the code - like you want to isolate the business rules in their own classes?

Comment: I'd probably go with some kind of enumeration for 'which' rule and store it's int in your DB. Then you could use a switch off that and just iterate over the rules to apply from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add new behavior to your code without rebuilding it you don't need to reinvent the wheel, use plugins.

You must supply an interface your plugins classes have to implement and if you don't want to restart your application a way to load these dlls at run-time using reflection.

I can give you more details if needed but internet is full of information about developing C# plugins. Using the DB to store behavior instead of data sounds like  a code smell to me.

Comment: I will look into the plugins idea. Thanks!

Comment: If you think it is the solution please accept the answer.